# Solr on a .NET site

Tags: lucene, solr, lucene.net, faceted-search

I've got an ASP.NET site backed with a SQL Server database. I'm been using Lucene.NET to index and search the database. I'm adding faceted search navigation to the results page (the facets are a hiarchical category tree). I asked yesterday to make sure I was using the right technique for faceting. All I've gotten so far is a suggestion to use Solr, but Solr does a *lot* of things I don't need.

I would really like to know from anyone who is familiar with the Solr's source code if Solr's facet processing is terribly different from the [one described here by Bert Willems](http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/faceted-search-and-drill-down-lucenenet/). Bascially you have a Lucene filter for each facet, you get the bits array from it, and you count the set bits in the array.

I'm thinking since mine is hiarchical to begin with I should be able to optimize this pretty well, but I'm afraid I might be grossly under-estimating the impact of this design on search performance. If Solr is no quicker, I'm not going to gain anything by using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a prototype project modeling your faceting needs with Solr and benchmark it against Lucene.net.

Even though [faceting in Solr](http://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/solr/src/java/org/apache/solr/request/SimpleFacets.java) is very optimized (and gets new optimizations all the time, like the [parallel per-segment faceting method](http://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/solr/src/java/org/apache/solr/request/PerSegmentSingleValuedFaceting.java)), when using Solr there is some overhead, for example network roundtrips and response parsing.

If your code already implements Lucene.NET, performs adequately and you don't need any of Solr's additional features, then there is no need to switch to Solr. But also consider that if you choose Solr you will get faceting performance boosts for free with each new version.